# PHP Pagination Limit

Tags: php

In my controller I have the following code:

```
if($action=='shipping_list'){ 
    $numrows=inquire_row(); //Get number of rows in query
    $pages= new Paginator('10', 'p'); //create object
    $pages->set_total($numrows);
    $shipping=shipping_list(); //Goes to model
    include('shipping_list.php');
}
```

In my model I these codes:

```
function shipping_list(){
    global $MEMS;
    global $pages;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM Inventory " .$pages->get_limit()
        ." WHERE Yield >=320 AND (Q = 'Pass' OR Q='No Q') AND shipdate = ' '
        ORDER BY Wafer ASC, RC ASC";
    $shipping = $MEMS -> query($query);
    return $shipping;
}
```

The object get_limit is suppose to output a query that starts the query depends on what page the user is on:

```
public function __contruct($perPage, $instance){
    $this->_instance = $instance;       
$this->_perPage = $perPage; 
}

public function get_limit(){
    return "LIMIT ".$this->get_start().",$this->_perPage";
}
```

However, when I echo $query, I get the following:

```
SELECT * FROM Inventory LIMIT 0, WHERE Yield >=320 AND (Q = 'Pass' OR Q='No Q') AND shipdate = ' ' ORDER BY Wafer ASC, RC ASC
```

So for some reason, the _perPage constant doesn't output. I'm new to OOP so any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong naming for construct:-

```
 public function __contruct($perPage, $instance){
                      ^
```

It should be

```
public function __construct($perPage, $instance){
```